# What is the difference between PackageType: Image and build --use-container in a SAM App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, aws-lambda-containers

`PackageType: image` seems to require a Dockerfile (looking at the hello-world example) along with `ImageUri` and `Metadata`
And it also doesn't want me to use `Runtime, Handler, Layers` (not even using layers)

whereas `build --use-container` does not seem to need anything. Does it figure it all out from the `Runtime: nodejs14.x-v1`

In the documentation I don't see anything

When I google there are tons of docs and resources but none related

I would really like to know because I'm at building a pipeline stage now. I got it to work great with a single stage and would now like to use the multi-stage multi-account and from what I read, it is recommended to use Images.

I noticed that the current pipeline does have `--use-container`, but my `PackageType` is `zip`, and at some point when I built it (using `sam pipeline --bootstrap`) it asked me if any of my functions use images. I would like for my multi stage/account one to answer `Y`

It may not be related, but that is also how I plan on using environment variables for each account, since the databases used to fetch data are different.
So I think I'll have to go and add `--container-env-var-file` in the gitlab-ci.yml script, or maybe in the `samconfig.toml [dev.build.parameters]` and under [prod.build.parameters]`for its`env-prod.json` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAM application package types can be either Zip or Images (container images). The details of their differences are described in their docs here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html

I came across that page  when I was reading the AWS docs for auto-creating a new SAM app here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/serverless-apps.html#serverless-apps-create

(when you need to: "Choose the runtime for your AWS SAM application")